# How to prevent a page break between this colored box and its subsequent text?

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

In the following code, how to prevent a page break between the colored box and its subsequent text?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipbelow=2em,skipabove=2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{mdframed}[innertopmargin=9pt,innerbottommargin=9pt,usetwoside=false,backgroundcolor=yellow]
\normalfont\Large\bfseries Notes
\end{mdframed}
\noindent Note 1: Bla bla\\
Note 2: Foo Bar\\
And other notes which can span several pages...
\end{document}
```

Please note that I want at least three lines of notes to be always under the box on a same page, otherwise both the box and its notes should go to the next page.

Comment: If you know how large the frame is in advance (in this case, it is quite short vertically), you can `\usepackage{needspace}` and then "require" the space before the frame, as in `\needspace{2\baselineskip}\begin{mdframed}...`.  Obviously, this approach will not work for frames that you wish to break across pages.

Comment: `tcolorbox` provides for breakable boxes definitely

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thanks, but I'd prefer not to use additional package. Also the height of my boxes is fixed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I think the OP wants to avoid a break not only within the box, but also after it.

Comment: Then how about this?: `\setbox0=\vbox{\begin{mdframed}[innertopmargin=9pt,innerbottommargin=9pt,usetwoside=false,backgroundcolor=yellow]
\normalfont\Large\bfseries Notes
\end{mdframed}
\noindent Note 1: Bla bla\\
Note 2: Foo Bar\\
And other notes which can span several pages...
}
\box0`.  Of course, this will also not allow breaking within the box.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I want to avoid a page break just after the box, not within the box, because the height of my boxes is fixed in the whole of my thesis.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes your solution has two problem: 1. there is an undesired vertical space above the box on page two. 2. my notes are sometimes 2-3 pages long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I originally suggested a `needspace` approach to the OP by way of a comment (and still think it the best approach), the OP prefers not to load additional packages.  So here is an alternative.

After some discussion in the comments, this approach (I think) remedies the two issues noted by the OP.  The vertical space at the beginning of the page is remedied by issuing a `\vspace{}` before the `\box` and issuing its negative counterpart as the first item within the box.  This will not affect the result in the middle of a page, but will apply the negative `\vspace` only if it occurs at the beginning of the page (to counteract the top-skip of the `mdframe`).

As to the second issue.  One need not include the multiple pages of notes inside the box... only those line that one wishes to remain unbroken with the `mdframe` header.

At the OP's request, I have wrapped it into a macro similar to `\section`.  The syntax is `\mysection{Section name}{after text}` where the "after text" will be guaranteed not to break from the header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipbelow=2em,skipabove=2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\newcommand\mysection[2]{%
 \setbox0=\vbox{\vspace{-2em}%
  \begin{mdframed}[innertopmargin=9pt,innerbottommargin=9pt,usetwoside=false,backgroundcolor=yellow]
    \normalfont\Large\bfseries #1
  \end{mdframed}
  \noindent #2%
 }
 \vspace{2em}\box0\noindent\ignorespaces%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\mysection{Notes}{%
Note 1: Bla bla\\
Note 2: Foo Bar
}
And other notes which can span several pages...\par
\lipsum[1]
\mysection{Notes}{%
Note 1: Bla bla\\
Note 2: Foo Bar
}
And other notes which can span several pages...\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but isn't there really an automatic way like the `\section{...}` mechanism?

Comment: @Sisabe I have turned it into a macro for you.

Answer (score 1):

If `tcolorbox` could be a solution following code could be a starting point. It defines a `notes` environment which includes a default "Notes" title with all notes. This box is breakable between pages, but at least 3 notes lines are included before a page break, otherwise the whole box starts in a new page. If for any reason the box should not be breakables, option `breakable=false` can be used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\newtcolorbox{notes}[1][]{title=Notes, left=0pt, right=0pt, lefttitle=4mm, toptitle=3mm, bottomtitle=3mm, boxrule=0mm, sharp corners, fonttitle=\normalfont\Large\bfseries, colbacktitle=yellow, coltitle=black, colback=white, lines before break=3, breakable, enhanced,#1}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{notes}[breakable=false]
\noindent Note 1: Bla bla\\
Note 2: Foo Bar\\
\lipsum[1]
\end{notes}
\end{document}
```

[image]